# Is Lorentz factor isotropic?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum

If a particle is moving in the xy-plane, such that the momentum $P = m v \gamma$.

Is $\gamma$ the same whenever we use it?

For example ,, if we would like to calculate the momentum in the x-direction, when substituting $v$ in $\gamma$ , do we use $v$ total or $v_x$ ?

Comment: How is $\gamma$ defined?

Comment: $\gamma$ = 1/ (1-($v$/$c$)^2)^.5

Comment: So what is $v^2$?

Comment: v is the velocity of the particle, and c is the speed of light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the momentum and velocity are vectors (more precisely 3-vectors) so the equation should be written:

$$ \mathbf p = \gamma m \mathbf v $$

This is true regardless of the direction of $\mathbf v$. The $v$ in the Lorentz factor is the magnitude of $\mathbf v$ so it is independent of the direction of $\mathbf v$.